# Erros diversos de autenticação quando edita uma pergunta

Tags: bug, status-intencional, edição

Isso ocorreu agora há pouco quando eu estava editando essa pergunta:

[Erro 500 no servidor- URL inválida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96455/erro-500-no-servidor-url-inv%C3%A1lida/96467#96467)

No momento que salvei a edição, deu erro dizendo que eu não poderia editar. Não lembro a mensagem exata no momento.

Então eu recarreguei a página e consegui editar e salvar, porém, haviam coisas um pouco estranhas.

O link "*editar*" estava diferente, exibindo "*melhorar esta pergunta*".

Eu ignorei, pois achei que tinham modificado o label.

Ok, então quando fui postar uma resposta, surgiu uma tela perguntando se eu era um humano. É uma tela que tem um robô e um checbox para o captcha.

Cliquei no checkbox pensando que teria que digitar um captcha mas não houve nada. A tela fechou e a resposta foi salva.

Mas percebi que a página recarregou sozinha e quando terminou, eu estava deslogado.

Fiz o login pelo google account e voltei a página.

O link com label estranho "*melhorar esta pergunta*", tinha voltado como "*editar*" e havia uma edição pendente. `editar(1)`

Percebi aí que a pergunta original estava ainda lá, não tinha salvo a minha edição.

Cliquei no "editar" e estava lá o que eu modifiquei, porém está como `anônimo`.

Uma confusão... não sei se alguém está conseguindo entender esse meu texto. rsrs

Mas enfim, estou reportando pois pode ser relevante para os programadores que cuidam do stack.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[UPDATE]

Aprovei a edição que ficou pendente como anônimo e agora está como "*editado por Comunidade*".

Comment: Eu vi essa edição, pois também editei a mesma pergunta depois. Eu havia achado isso muito estranho.

Answer (score 4):

Eu entendi. Em algum momento, entre o início da sua edição e o momento que você foi salvá-la você foi deslogado do Stack Exchange, a interface que apareceu para você então era a se quem estava deslogado. Ao invés de "editar" aparece "melhorar esta pergunta" no lugar, é possível comprovar isso abrindo uma janela anônima do seu navegador e ver como os usuários não logados enxergam a interface.

Sugestões de edições de usuários não registrados vão para a fila de análise da comunidade, e como não há registro do usuário o autor da sugestão fica definido como "anônimo". Já o captcha deve ter sido ativado justamente por você ter sugerido a edição como um usuário anônimo, para evitar ataques de vandalismos lotando a fila de análises de edição.

A edição ficou lá pendente e quando você se logou você analisou a edição que você havia sugerido com usuário anônimo.

Para isso se tornar relevante acredito que seria necessário você conseguir entender e reproduzir um bug que te desloga automaticamente para então ser reportado e tratado pela equipe de desenvolvedores, pois basicamente o mistério todo da situação agora é saber como você foi acontecer de se deslogar, intencionalmente ou não.

Comment: Exato! Descreveu perfeitamente o ocorrido. Tenho certeza de que não me desloguei. Acho que o "logout" pode ter ocorrido no primeiro momento quando tentei salvar a edição. Acho que naquele ponto o site não conseguiu ver a minha autenticação.

Comment: Pois então, os motivos para ter sido deslogado são muitos, pode ser que a cada X dias você é deslogado e é obrigado a se logar novamente, como alguma forma de proteção, ou o sistema te deslogou por detectar algum tipo de ação suspeita vindo do seu IP, enfim.. são só chutes. Se você enfrentar muitas ocorrências de deslogamentos não intencionais tente observar um padrão e volte a relatar aqui no meta, mas se foi só essa vez acredito que não é nada que mereça atenção.

Comment: @Math onde há fumo há fogo. O bicho depois vem te pegar um dia ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. do que você está falando??

Comment: @Math "mas se foi só essa vez acredito que não é nada que mereça atenção".

Comment: Eu uso o site de 2 computadores diferentes e pelo menos 2 dispositivos móveis, e sou deslogado com alguma frequência. No tablet, é praticamente todo dia.

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu também uso o site em 2 computadores diferentes e 2 dispositivos móveis diferentes, mas raramento sou deslogado. Deve ser um pouco chato isso que você passa.